# How to implement spring data mongo multidatabase transactions

Tags: spring, mongodb, transactions, multiple-databases

I created an application that copies data from one database to another one based on this [tutorial](https://dzone.com/articles/multiple-mongodb-connectors-with-spring-boot).
In fact, I need to make a method that inserts in two different databases transactional.
Is this possible with MongoDB ? and how can I implement it?

Comment: If both databases are in the same deployment (e.g. server), it should work - pass the same session to all operations. If databases are in different deployments they don't coordinate.

Comment: You should declare a transaction manager that uses a unique datasource. You should choose one of the two databases in the transaction manager bean declaration. So, only the operations that deal with this database will be transactional. Could you put the documentation used to say that if the two databases are on the same server, the transaction management will work ?

Comment: I haven't tested it but I expect it to work.

Comment: @Abderrahmen https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/ 'With distributed transactions, transactions can be used across multiple operations, collections, databases, documents, and shards.', so this is at least supported by MongoDB itself.

Answer (score 0):

To use multi-document transactions in MongoDB across multiple databases in Spring Data MongoDB, you need to configure a `MongoTemplate` per database, but all of them must use the same `MongoDbFactory` because it is treated as the transactional resource.

This means that you will need to override a couple of methods of `MongoTemplate` to make it use the database it should use (and not the one configured inside `SimpleMongoClientDbFactory`).

Let's assume that your databases are called 'one' and 'two'. Then it goes like this:

```
public class MongoTemplateWithFixedDatabase extends MongoTemplate {
    private final MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory;
    private final String databaseName;

    public MongoTemplateWithFixedDatabase(MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory,
            MappingMongoConverter mappingMongoConverter, String databaseName) {
        super(mongoDbFactory, mappingMongoConverter);
        this.mongoDbFactory = mongoDbFactory;
        this.databaseName = databaseName;
    }

    @Override
    protected MongoDatabase doGetDatabase() {
        return MongoDatabaseUtils.getDatabase(databaseName, mongoDbFactory, ON_ACTUAL_TRANSACTION);
    }
}
```

and

```
@Bean
public MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory() {
    // here, some 'default' database name is configured, the following MongoTemplate instances will ignore it
    return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(mongoClient(), getDatabaseName());
}

@Bean
public MongoTransactionManager mongoTransactionManager() {
    return new MongoTransactionManager(mongoDbFactory());
}

@Bean
public MongoTemplate mongoTemplateOne(MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory,
        MappingMongoConverter mappingMongoConverter) {
    MongoTemplate template = new MongoTemplateWithFixedDatabase(mongoDbFactory,
            mappingMongoConverter, "one");
    return template;
}

@Bean
public MongoTemplate mongoTemplateTwo(MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory,
        MappingMongoConverter mappingMongoConverter) {
    MongoTemplate template = new MongoTemplateWithFixedDatabase(mongoDbFactory,
            mappingMongoConverter, "two");
    return template;
}
```

Then just inject `mongoTemplateOne` and `mongoTemplateTwo` in your service, mark its method with `@Transactional` and it should work.

## Reactive case

In the reactive case, it's very similar. Of course, you need to use reactive versions of the classes like `ReactiveMongoTemplate`, `ReactiveMongoDatabaseFactory`, `ReactiveMongoTransactionManager`.

There is also a couple of caveats. First, you have to override 3 methods, not 2 (as `getCollection(String)` also needs to be overridden). Also, I had to do it with an abstract class to make it work:

```
@Bean
public ReactiveMongoOperations reactiveMongoTemplateOne(
        @ReactiveMongoDatabaseFactory reactiveMongoDatabaseFactory,
        MappingMongoConverter mappingMongoConverter) {
    ReactiveMongoTemplate template = new ReactiveMongoTemplate(reactiveMongoDatabaseFactory,
            mappingMongoConverter) {

        @Override
        protected Mono<MongoDatabase> doGetDatabase() {
            return ReactiveMongoDatabaseUtils.getDatabase("one", reactiveMongoDatabaseFactory,
                    ON_ACTUAL_TRANSACTION);
        }

        @Override
        public MongoDatabase getMongoDatabase() {
            return reactiveMongoDatabaseFactory.getMongoDatabase(getDatabaseName());
        }

        @Override
        public MongoCollection<Document> getCollection(String collectionName) {
            Assert.notNull(collectionName, "Collection name must not be null!");

            try {
                return reactiveMongoDatabaseFactory.getMongoDatabase(getDatabaseName())
                        .getCollection(collectionName);
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                throw potentiallyConvertRuntimeException(e,
                        reactiveMongoDatabaseFactory.getExceptionTranslator());
            }
        }

        private RuntimeException potentiallyConvertRuntimeException(RuntimeException ex,
                PersistenceExceptionTranslator exceptionTranslator) {
            RuntimeException resolved = exceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ex);
            return resolved == null ? ex : resolved;
        }
    };
    return template;
}
```

P.S. the provided code was tested with spring-data-mongodb 2.2.4.